# Expandable list view + layout in Android apps

Tags: android, scrollview, expandablelistview, mobile-application

I was doing an android apps which require the scroll feature and expandable list view feature.
First, I have a linear layout contain some text view. Below the text view, I have an expandable list view.
Then I want set the whole layout to scrollable. So I add the scroll view to the layout. But it will make the expandable list view only show first row.
I want make the whole layout scrollable not just expandable list view can scroll only.
Any solution can help or another way to do this.

Comment: Make the text view the header view of expandable list view. That way the whole layout will scroll. Just place the content in linearlayout content in header view of expandable listview.

Answer (score 0):

Put the part of the layout above the list view into the list view's header.  This will make it scroll as part of the list view.